# How does a VPN client transfers all the network traffic through a tunnel?

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy

When you want to use a proxy, you need to set the socket address of proxy server at client application so it connects to the server and transfers the data. But when using a VPN client, it automatically transfers all the data through the tunnel without the need to set the server address for every application.

I want to know how does VPN do this? How can I transfer all the network traffic through a tunnel, and is it possible to create a simple VPN with my own defined protocol?

Thanks

Comment: Try this  https://www.shrew.net/download/vpn   and see if you can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Glad you moved the question to this site, where it is more likely to find answers than on SO. I'm your first upvote here ^^

Comment: @John , I'm not looking for a VPN. I want to know how it works.

Comment: @finnmglas. Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with *routing*. Say you have a packet for 8.8.8.8, and your Ethernet address is 192.168.1.1. If you wanted to contact 192.168.1.25 it would be OK, it's in your same network (probably) and you have its physical address, but 8.8.8.8 is not local. What do you do? You send the packet to your *local gateway*, trusting that *it* will know what to do (and it will in turn send the packet to the appropriate gateway).

Say you have *two* network cards. You need to send the same packet, through which interface you send it? The routing table specifies what networks are reachable from which interface, and one such "network" is the default network, "everywhere else", 0.0.0.0/0.

The VPN client simply de-registers whatever the old default route was, and rewrites it to say, "all traffic to 0.0.0.0/0 must be routed through the newly minted VPN0 interface".

Then traffic to your local network still goes outside the VPN, but now "everything else" is consigned to VPN0, which encrypts it and sends it to the VPN server (through the *old* interface).

## Building your own VPN system

In short, it's **complicated**. Going through the mechanism above, it's clear you need:

- a network interface driver. You need to present yourself to the system as a network interface card, with specific features and capabilities. This driver will accept packets from the system.
- an encryption module, that will take those packets and encrypt them. This is the easiest part since you'll just be using an established encryption library (the Golden Rule on rolling your own crypto is "**JUST DON'T**").
- a network client module, that will connect to the VPN server somehow, and handle the connection (reconnections, errors, **authentication**, exchange of crypto info from the encryption module)
- a network server module, dual of the client.

To tell you frankly, the part I wouldn't know how to go about is the first. But you can find [source code examples](https://www.softether.org/5-download/src) and start from there. In point of fact, to "roll your own VPN" you probably only need to modify either the client/server part, and maybe the encryption module to choose the algorithm or tweak the features.

If you want to VPN a single protocol or port, unfortunately **you cannot** - not in your VPN software that is. Remember, that is seen as a network card. You can't get a card that will only route TCP, because the card *does not know anything* about protocols - it's lower in the ISO/OSI stack. For that, then, you need to instruct the *system* to only route certain protocols, addresses and/or ports through your interface. In Linux you would do this using e.g. [policy based routing](https://osric.com/chris/accidental-developer/2019/03/linux-policy-based-routing/), adding a marker to the packets that interest you and sending those, and those alone, to the VPN interface.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please give more details about the way I can create a VPN?